# html 2 div containers positioning

Tags: html, css

I created a . In this article i want to create 2 divs. 1 div with an image and the other div with text. I created these both elements. But still not work. The text should be up not down like now...

Here is my Code

```css
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Raleway;
}

body{
    background-image: url(images/hintergrund.png);
}

section{
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 60%;
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
 box-shadow: 8px 8px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

article{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.one{
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200x200");
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.two{
    
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Homepage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <article>
                <div class="one">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="two">
                    exampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexamplexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexaexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexaexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexaexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexaexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexaeexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexamplempleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexample
                </div>
            </article>
            <article>
            </article>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a jsfiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76739xw7/)

And if i write a long text, the text will run out of the section. How can i fix that?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/76739xw7/4/
The problem is that your div .one is not floating anywhere so nothing will be to the right of it. Another problem is that your .two needs a width and to float as well to be able to be next to one. Add some padding. A way to make words able to break is with css3s word-wrap property, my code here:

```
<body>
        <section>
            <article>
                <div class="one">

                </div>
                <div class="two">
                    exampleexampleexampleexampleexamplexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexaexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexaexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexaexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexaexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexaeexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexample
                </div>
            </article>
            <article>
            </article>
        </section>
    </body>

*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Raleway;
}

body{
    background-image: url(images/hintergrund.png);
}

section{
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 60%;
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

article{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.one{
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200x200");
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    float:left;
}

.two{
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two DIV's next to each other, as they are both BLOCK level elements they will appear on top of each other.

If you want to put them side-by-side you can make them Float, or use Inline-Block

To make the text sit in the middle of the box you can add padding to the box or use line-height